Denoting the extra dimension in derivative of matrix
Suppose I have two vectors $x \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times 1}$ and $y \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times 1}$. Then the outer product $xy^T \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$. I am interested in computing:
$$
\frac{d}{dx}xy^T
$$
I'm pretty certain this should yield a 3D tensor, but I'm confused on several aspects:

Is the resulting 3D tensor of shape $(m, n, m$) or $(m, m, n)$?
How would the result be denoted? Concretely,

$$
\frac{d}{dx}xy^T = \frac{dx}{dx}y^T + x\frac{dy}{dx} = Iy^T
$$
but the $\frac{dx}{dx}$ does not make sense to me: the product $Iy^T$ does not work by matrix rules--so I wonder if in applying the product rule in multivariate calculus, a different product is used that adds a new dimension.
Edited to add: I messed up and forgot that $d/dx$ means the total derivative--I used it above to mean the gradient instead.

One of the advantages of index notation is that since $xy^T=x^iy_j$ (Euclidean inner product space) then $\frac{\partial}{\partial x^k} x^i y_j = \delta^i_k y_j$. This is a third order tensor. If $m=2$ and $n=3$ you could write $\delta^i_k y_j=\left[\begin{matrix}
\left[\begin{matrix}
y_1 & 0 \
0 & y_1
\end{matrix}\right] \
\left[\begin{matrix}
y_2 & 0 \
0 & y_2
\end{matrix}\right] \
\left[\begin{matrix}
y_3 & 0 \
0 & y_3
\end{matrix}\right]
\end{matrix}\right]$

$
\def\R#1{{\mathbb R}^{#1}}
\def\P{{\large\cal P}}
\def\ee{{\large e}}
\def\e{{\large\varepsilon}}
\def\d{{\large\delta}}
\def\k{\otimes} \def\s{\star}
\def\o{{\tt1}}
\def\G{{\large\Gamma}}
\def\BR#1{\Big(#1\Big)}
\def\LR#1{\left(#1\right)}
\def\op#1{\operatorname{#1}}
\def\vc#1{\op{vec}\LR{#1}}
\def\trace#1{\op{Tr}\LR{#1}}
\def\frob#1{\left\| #1 \right\|_F}
\def\q{\quad}      \def\qq{\qquad}
\def\qif{\q\iff\q} \def\qiq{\q\implies\q}
\def\p{\partial}   \def\grad#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}
\def\red#1{\color{red}{#1}}
\def\green#1{\color{green}{#1}}
\def\CLR#1{\red{\LR{#1}}}
\def\fracLR#1#2{\LR{\frac{#1}{#2}}}
\def\gradLR#1#2{\LR{\grad{#1}{#2}}}
$The gradient of a vector with respect to its $k^{th}$ component
is the $k^{th}$ basis vector, i.e.
$$\eqalign{
\e_k^Tx = x_k
 &\qif x = \sum_{k=\o}^m \e_k\,x_k
 &\qiq \grad x{x_k} = \e_k \in\R{m}
\\
\ee_k^Ty = y_k
 &\qif y = \sum_{k=\o}^n \ee_k\,y_k
 &\qiq \grad y{y_k} = \ee_k\in\R{n}
\\
}$$
Now consider the derivative of your outer product wrt a component of $x$
$$\eqalign{
A &= xy^T \qiq
\grad A{x_k} &= \gradLR x{x_k}\,y^T \;=\; \e_k\,y^T \\
}$$
Let's extract the $(i,j)$ component from this matrix-valued result
$$\eqalign{
\G_{ijk} \doteq \grad{A_{ij}}{x_k}
 \;=\; \e_i^T\gradLR A{x_k}\ee_j 
 \;=\; \e_i^T\LR{\e_k\,y^T}\ee_j 
 \;=\; \d_{ik}\,y_j
}$$
where $\d_{ik}$ is the Kronecker delta symbol, i.e. the components of the identity matrix
$$\eqalign{
I_{ik} \,=\, \e_i^T\LR I\e_k \,=\, \e_i^T\e_k \,=\, \d_{ik} \\
}$$
The dimensions of the gradient tensor (as defined above) are
$$ \G\in\R{{m\times n}\times{m}} $$
however this is just one convention.
The other common convention orders the tensor components as
$$\eqalign{
\G_{{i}jk} \doteq \grad{A_{jk}}{x_{i}} \,=\, \d_{ij}\,y_k
 \qif \G=I\s y \q \{ {\sf dyadic\ product} \}
}$$
in which case
$\; \G\in\R{{m}\times{m\times n}} $

I see. I've been using the latter (but using $\otimes$ to denote the tensor outer product, which I think is the same as the dyadic product?), and I wasn't quite sure if that was right. Should I think of the dyadic product as "embedding" $y$ into the identity tensor?

@Rahul Usage varies from field to field.  The symbol $\otimes$ denotes the Kronecker product in Matrix Calculus and allied fields. But in various Engineering disciplines it represents the dyadic product.  In Physics simple juxtaposition is used, but that implies a matrix product for mathematicians.  It's a real mess.  I picked $\star$ since it seems the least likely to be misinterpreted.

Oh my god, that explains so much. In searching before asking here, I cannot tell you how many times I've gotten different notations that everyone else says means something else. I could never find a straight answer on where the extra dimension came from, from a notation perspective.

$
\newcommand\dd{\mathrm d}
\newcommand\DD[2]{\frac{\dd#1}{\dd#2}}
\newcommand\dD{\mathrm D}
$The issue is that this is bad notation.
With this notation you have to treat $\dd/\dd x$ as matrix-like, meaning you cannot move it around like you did in your attempt at a product rule, and not only that but we have to distinguish between matrix multiplication and tensor products. So, treating $\dd/\dd x$ as a row vector, there are three different possible derivatives:
$$
  \DD{}{\dot x}\dot xy^T,\quad \dot xy^T\left(\DD{}{\dot x}\right)^T,\quad \DD{}{\dot x}\otimes(\dot xy^T).
$$
We could put the tensor product on the right or also transpose the derivative operator in the tensor product expressions, but doing so gives essentially the same quantity. Because the location of $\dd/\dd x$ is important, we cannot use a "differentiate-to-the-right" convention, and instead explicitly denote what is differentiated with overdots.
You can view $\dd/\dd x$ as a row vector of partial derivatives; it then becomes clear that
$$
  \DD{}{\dot x}\dot xy^T = my^T,\quad \dot xy^T\left(\DD{}{\dot x}\right)^T = y,\quad \DD{}{\dot x}\otimes(\dot xy^T) = \sum_ie^i\otimes(\partial_ixy^T) = \sum_ie^i\otimes(e_iy^T).
$$
The latter could be written in index notation simply as
$$
  \partial_ix^jy_k = \delta^j_iy_k.
$$
If we recognize the outer product as a tensor product, then we could instead write
$$
  \DD{}{\dot x}\otimes(\dot xy^T) = \sum_ie^i\otimes e_i\otimes y^T = I\otimes y^T
$$
where $I$ is the identity (1,1)-tensor.
There is also a fourth possibility. The total differential gives a linear transformation $\dot\dD[\dot xy^T]$ for each value of $x$, and the total differential of a linear transformation (which $x \mapsto xy^T$ is) is that transformation itself independent of $x$:
$$
  \dot\dD[\dot xy^T](h) = hy^T.
$$
A derivative is often something you multiply with $h$ to get the total differential, so we could also say that $y^T$ is the derivative.
The moral of the story is that there are multiple not-quite-the-same "derivatives" you could use, and you have to decide which is appropriate for your use case. Do notice, however, that the essential data of all these derivatives is just the components of $y$.

I think I messed up in that I probably meant the gradient instead of the total derivative when I used d/dx, which is why I expect a 3D tensor out of (what I should've written as) $\nabla_x (xy^T)$.
